# Web development with just Python Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

Is it just fine to build a website with a python backend that interacts with the database and use flask to display it on html? flask can also get inputs from the html form and from there python can manipulate it. Is there any security concern with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly safe, provided you take safeguards and use best practices. Flask is my favorite Python web server framework - extremely lightweight and flexible, makes the fewest assumptions about your application.

Answer (score -1):

I think flask is the best framework for web development. It is more flexible then django. You can connect database easily and security is so strong in python flask. Over all it is best for webdevelopment. You can also use jinja with falsk.